# JMeter is Skipping second Get HTTP request in a thread geoup

Tags: performance, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

To the left of the screenshot, I'm executing two 2 HTTP get requests (Same URL) marked in yellow. but as you see in the right side the Get request was executed only once and skipped the second time.

what am I doing wrong here?

[Please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m97uG.png)

Answer (score 0):

JMeter shouldn't "skip" requests, I can think of the following reasons:

1. You're running the test with more than 1 thread (virtual user) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), if this is the case - the sequential order of requests execution will not be guaranteed, you will need to add [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function in order to be able to distinguish the responses coming from different virtual users.
2. An error preventing the request from execution occurred, if this is the case - most probably the reason is in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (you might need to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) in order to get more information)